# Как можно передать значение переменной "x" arduino?

Tags: железо, python, serial, usb

Adrduino C:

```
#define led 13
int x = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  x = Serial.read();
  if (x==1){
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   
  }
  if (x==2){
   digitalWrite(led, LOW);   
  }
}
```

Python 2.7:

```
import serial

serialPort = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
serialPort.open()
serialPort.write('2')
serialPort.close()
```

Или ткните носом где прочитать.

Comment: Вот тут http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/serial не про это написано? Или тут:http://www.ladyada.net/learn/arduino/lesson4.html

Comment: На оф. сайте это первом делом посмотрел. Дело в том, что этот код должен работать, но он не работает, в чем дело не могу понять.

Comment: Какой код? Тот который Вы привели? Если это всё -- то не должен. Если не всё -- обращайтесь к экстрасенсу.

И ещё. Чтобы не лазить по докам, разбираясь с умолчаниями, лучше сразу указывайте не только скорость, но и формат символа.

Comment: вот пример тут пример, похожий http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/02/python-interfacing-with-an-arduino/, его пробовал не работает.

Comment: диод Led не загорается. Я хочу чтобы переменная 'x' принимала значение '1' или '2', в зависимости от значения диод загорался или выключался.

Comment: Вопрос на засыпку: осциллограф есть? С осциллографом (зациклив посылку символа) можно и формат символа посмотреть (полезно, если у Вас форматы со стороны микроконроллера и компа не совпадают).

Comment: осциллографа нет.

Comment: Значит там, где другой просто бы посмотрел сигнал придётся читать документацию и думать. (Кроме осциллографов бывают ещё приборы попроще: тестеры, пробники и т.д. Заменить в общем случае осциллограф не могут, но некоторые вещи можно посмотреть и с их помощью).

Answer (score 1):

Привет, @Vorlog. Я тоже с этим провозился. Ответ нашел простой. В .Serial надо задать параметр dsrdtr = 1, тогда вске работает.

Вот мой код (идею взял отсюда http://podrugomu.com/node/981)

```
import viz
import serial

viz.go()

def Func():
    value = '1' 

    my_com_port = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600, dsrdtr = 1, timeout = 0);
    print my_com_port.name

    my_com_port.write(value)
    print ''' -- send -- ''', value

    my_com_port.close()

vizact.ontimer(1,Func);
```

Код писал в Vizard, поэтому тут 2 специфичные функции: viz.go и vizact.ontimer, - но они задают просто перманентный таймер, чтобы раз в 1 секунду отправлять сигнал (символ) на плату. В остальном, все то же, что и в обычном питоне.

Answer (score 0):

Пример скорее всего не работает по причине того, что Arduino сбрасывается, когда вы из питона открываете порт. В первую очередь нужно проверить это. А во-вторых, порт нужно полностью инициализировать. Подробнее см. [здесь](http://sites.google.com/site/vanyambauseslinux/arduino/host-klient-arduino-na-s-linux)